# Silverstripe UserDefinedForm module breaks javascript

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have an website running on **Silverstripe CMS 3.5.2 & Framework 3.5.3**. I have a template for the Homepage. On the homepage I want to add a Form using the **UserDefinedForm module**. I installed it correctly, and after changing

class **Homepage** extends **Page** to class **Homepage** extend **UserDefinedForm** and after a **dev/build?flush=1**,

my javascript is not working. I have a slider (bxslider), and I get the following error in the console:

```
 jQuery(...).bxSlider is not a function
```

The code that activates the bx slider is placed in the **Homepage_Controller** like this:

```
Requirements::customScript(<<<JS
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            auto: true,
            captions: true
        });              
    }); 
JS );
```

This initially looks like a javascript placement error, like jquery beeing loaded after the bxslider but it doesn't make any sense why before extending to UserDefinedForm, it was working.

Comment: Could it be that you have included jquery twice? Once manually and once by userdefinedform module? You can check it in your console / network tab.

Comment: Where do you include the javascript for "bxslider"?

Comment: I've had similar problems when using an UploadField on the front end. My solution was to use block the jquery that ships with silverstripe. Requirements::block( 'framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js' ); And then add all the scripts again that UploadField uses. This will add them after my version of jQuery. Requirements::javascript('framework/thirdparty/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'); + another 10 or so. I won't paste them here, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea @Gavin Bruce i'll try it. I didn't have time to debug  at the time, so I did the form myself without using the module. But I still want to fix this problem in one of this days, don't want to leave it like this.